# Beautiful Soup 'href' parse

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Let's suppose I want to parse the text in ALL hrefs in a page but my code doesn't seem to work. 
There are some snippets of code like this in the html document I want to parse.

```
<td class="alt1" id="ID" title="SOMETEXT">
                <div>
                     <a href="THETEXTIWANT.html" id="SOME IDENTIFIER">SOME TEXT.</a>
                </div>
</td>
```

This is the code I am trying to run

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,
    for td in parse.find_all(class_="alt1"):
        a = str(div.get())
        f.writelines(a + '\n')
```

Comment: `[tag.text for tag in soup.find_all(href=True)]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_all(href=True)`

```
for td in parse.find_all(class_="alt1"):
    for href in td.find_all(href=True):
        print(href.text)
```